# No GPU Kernel PMU event in perf list Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: linux, gpu, intel, perf

I am currently having great success monitoring energy consumption using RAPL via PERF. However, I would like to also monitor processes on GPU.

Looking at the documentation, https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/performance/perf.html, my current system only has `cores`,`pkg` and `ram`.

I see that the documentation states that not all processors and GPU's support the `GPU` uncore domain, however I am on  a relatively new computer and I was wondering if something can be done on my part?

Processor:

```
Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Address sizes:                   39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
CPU(s):                          12
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-11
Vendor ID:                       GenuineIntel
Model name:                      Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10400F CPU @ 2.90GHz
CPU family:                      6
Model:                           165
Thread(s) per core:              2
Core(s) per socket:              6
Socket(s):                       1
Stepping:                        3
CPU max MHz:                     4300.0000
CPU min MHz:                     800.0000
BogoMIPS:                        5799.77
Flags:                           fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp ibrs_enhanced fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp md_clear flush_l1d arch_capabilities
L1d cache:                       192 KiB (6 instances)
L1i cache:                       192 KiB (6 instances)
L2 cache:                        1.5 MiB (6 instances)
L3 cache:                        12 MiB (1 instance)
NUMA node(s):                    1
NUMA node0 CPU(s):               0-11
Vulnerability Itlb multihit:     KVM: Mitigation: VMX unsupported
Vulnerability L1tf:              Not affected
Vulnerability Mds:               Not affected
Vulnerability Meltdown:          Not affected
Vulnerability Mmio stale data:   Mitigation; Clear CPU buffers; SMT vulnerable
Vulnerability Retbleed:          Mitigation; Enhanced IBRS
Vulnerability Spec store bypass: Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl and seccomp
Vulnerability Spectre v1:        Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
Vulnerability Spectre v2:        Mitigation; Enhanced IBRS, IBPB conditional, RSB filling, PBRSB-eIBRS SW sequence
Vulnerability Srbds:             Mitigation; Microcode
Vulnerability Tsx async abort:   Not affected
```

And also for the GPU:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation TU116 [GeForce GTX 1660 SUPER] [10de:21c4] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. TU116 [GeForce GTX 1660 SUPER] [1043:872e]
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 141
        Memory at 91000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
        I/O ports at 4000 [size=128]
        Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [78] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
        Capabilities: [250] Latency Tolerance Reporting
```

Sadly, the output of `perf list` is too long, but the relevant ones are:

```
  branch-instructions OR branches                    [Hardware event]
  branch-misses                                      [Hardware event]
  bus-cycles                                         [Hardware event]
  cache-misses                                       [Hardware event]
  cache-references                                   [Hardware event]
  cpu-cycles OR cycles                               [Hardware event]
  instructions                                       [Hardware event]
  ref-cycles                                         [Hardware event]
  alignment-faults                                   [Software event]
  bpf-output                                         [Software event]
  cgroup-switches                                    [Software event]
  context-switches OR cs                             [Software event]
  cpu-clock                                          [Software event]
  cpu-migrations OR migrations                       [Software event]
  dummy                                              [Software event]
  emulation-faults                                   [Software event]
  major-faults                                       [Software event]
  minor-faults                                       [Software event]
  page-faults OR faults                              [Software event]
  task-clock                                         [Software event]
  duration_time                                      [Tool event]
  L1-dcache-load-misses                              [Hardware cache event]
  L1-dcache-loads                                    [Hardware cache event]
  L1-dcache-stores                                   [Hardware cache event]
  L1-icache-load-misses                              [Hardware cache event]
  LLC-load-misses                                    [Hardware cache event]
  LLC-loads                                          [Hardware cache event]
  LLC-store-misses                                   [Hardware cache event]
  LLC-stores                                         [Hardware cache event]
  branch-load-misses                                 [Hardware cache event]
  branch-loads                                       [Hardware cache event]
  dTLB-load-misses                                   [Hardware cache event]
  dTLB-loads                                         [Hardware cache event]
  dTLB-store-misses                                  [Hardware cache event]
  dTLB-stores                                        [Hardware cache event]
  iTLB-load-misses                                   [Hardware cache event]
  iTLB-loads                                         [Hardware cache event]
  node-load-misses                                   [Hardware cache event]
  node-loads                                         [Hardware cache event]
  node-store-misses                                  [Hardware cache event]
  node-stores                                        [Hardware cache event]
  branch-instructions OR cpu/branch-instructions/    [Kernel PMU event]
  branch-misses OR cpu/branch-misses/                [Kernel PMU event]
  bus-cycles OR cpu/bus-cycles/                      [Kernel PMU event]
  cache-misses OR cpu/cache-misses/                  [Kernel PMU event]
  cache-references OR cpu/cache-references/          [Kernel PMU event]
  cpu-cycles OR cpu/cpu-cycles/                      [Kernel PMU event]
  instructions OR cpu/instructions/                  [Kernel PMU event]
  mem-loads OR cpu/mem-loads/                        [Kernel PMU event]
  mem-stores OR cpu/mem-stores/                      [Kernel PMU event]
  ref-cycles OR cpu/ref-cycles/                      [Kernel PMU event]
  topdown-fetch-bubbles OR cpu/topdown-fetch-bubbles/ [Kernel PMU event]
  topdown-recovery-bubbles OR cpu/topdown-recovery-bubbles/ [Kernel PMU event]
  topdown-slots-issued OR cpu/topdown-slots-issued/  [Kernel PMU event]
  topdown-slots-retired OR cpu/topdown-slots-retired/ [Kernel PMU event]
  topdown-total-slots OR cpu/topdown-total-slots/    [Kernel PMU event]
  cstate_core/c3-residency/                          [Kernel PMU event]
  cstate_core/c6-residency/                          [Kernel PMU event]
  cstate_core/c7-residency/                          [Kernel PMU event]
  cstate_pkg/c10-residency/                          [Kernel PMU event]
  cstate_pkg/c2-residency/                           [Kernel PMU event]
  cstate_pkg/c3-residency/                           [Kernel PMU event]
  cstate_pkg/c6-residency/                           [Kernel PMU event]
  cstate_pkg/c7-residency/                           [Kernel PMU event]
  cstate_pkg/c8-residency/                           [Kernel PMU event]
  cstate_pkg/c9-residency/                           [Kernel PMU event]
  intel_bts//                                        [Kernel PMU event]
  intel_pt//                                         [Kernel PMU event]
  msr/aperf/                                         [Kernel PMU event]
  msr/cpu_thermal_margin/                            [Kernel PMU event]
  msr/mperf/                                         [Kernel PMU event]
  msr/pperf/                                         [Kernel PMU event]
  msr/smi/                                           [Kernel PMU event]
  msr/tsc/                                           [Kernel PMU event]
  power/energy-cores/                                [Kernel PMU event]
  power/energy-pkg/                                  [Kernel PMU event]
  power/energy-ram/                                  [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_cbox_0/clockticks/                          [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_cbox_1/clockticks/                          [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_cbox_2/clockticks/                          [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_cbox_3/clockticks/                          [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_cbox_4/clockticks/                          [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_cbox_5/clockticks/                          [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_imc/data_reads/                             [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_imc/data_writes/                            [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_imc/gt_requests/                            [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_imc/ia_requests/                            [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_imc/io_requests/                            [Kernel PMU event]
```

Am I just out of luck and on an outdated set-up, or can I add the GPU to the uncore domain?